# Hibernate : set the value in an association table

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, many-to-many

I have a classic n-to-n association between the tables `A` and `B`.

```
A --> AtoB --> B
```

so I mapped it like that:

```
<class table="A">
  <id column="id_A" />
  .../...
  <set table="AtoB" order-by="pos">
    <key column="id_A" />
    <many-to-many column="id_B" />
  </set>
</class>
```

The problem is with the column `pos` of the table `AtoB` which is used in the `order-by` clause, it works fine when I read the values, but how can I *set* the value in the column?

Comment: You should be deciding the value of **pos** while inserting data to **AtoB** right?